# Limit input to only print a fibonacci sequence up to 16 places?

Tags: java

I am have a program which prints off the fibonacci sequence up to a given input. The user puts in a number and it prints out the sequence up to that many numbers.

ex: input = 4 prints 1 1 2 3

I want to limit the program to only allowing an input 1-16. The way I have it now will print the sequence an then prints the error message? Any suggestions? Thank you

```
public class FibonacciGenerator 
{
    private int fibonacci = 1;

    public FibonacciGenerator()
    {

    }

    public int Fibonacci(int number)
    {
        if(number == 1 || number == 2)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (number > 16)
        {
            System.out.println("Error must select 1-16");
        }
        else
        {
            int fib1=1, fib2=1;
            for(int count= 3; count < 17 && count <= number; count++)
            {
                fibonacci = fib1 + fib2;
                fib1 = fib2;
                fib2 = fibonacci;
            }
        }
    return fibonacci;
    }
}
```

Here is my main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FibonacciPrinter 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer 1-16: ");
        int input = in.nextInt();

        FibonacciGenerator newNumber = new FibonacciGenerator();

        System.out.println("Fibonacci sequence up to " + input + " places.");

        for(int fibCount = 1; fibCount <= input; fibCount++)
        {
            int sequence = newNumber.Fibonacci(fibCount);
            System.out.print(sequence);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: First, Java method names are camel case starting with a lower case letter (so, `fibonacci` and not `Fibonacci`). Second, 16 numbers seems a strange limitation. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a recommendation don't make your methods or variables start with capital letter, capital letter is used by convention for Classes only.

Also, you should validate `input` variable **before** passing it to your method.

I mean:

```
if (input > 16 || input < 1) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-16");
}
else {

    for(int fibCount = 1; fibCount <= input; fibCount++)
    {
        int sequence = newNumber.Fibonacci(fibCount);
        System.out.print(sequence);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Great, I corrected the capital letter. I knew that, I just forgot. and that worked the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 3):

In your Fibonacci function, your first line should be an if statement to see if the number is greater than 16. If it is, then you can throw an error.

Below is what it should be:

```
public int Fibonacci(int number) {
    if (number > 16 || number < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error. Must select 1-16.");
    // Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. It is still printing the fibonacci sequence and then the error message.

Comment: Do you want the user to not input a number greater than 16 or do you want the fibonacci function to not receive a number greater than 16? If it is the latter, then it is my solution. If not, see @Frakcool's solution.

Comment: Well, I mean you could do more extensive check conditions on the input number but for this case, the person asked to just check for number being greater that 16.

Comment: Shoot, I messed up. Thanks for double checking on me @ChiefTwoPencils.

Answer (score 1):

In your Fibonacci function, for number not equal to 1 and 2. The return statement `return fibonacci;` will always be called. That's why the error message is printed with the sequence.

To avoid this, you can use @Frakcool method to validate variable `input` before passing it to Fibonacci function. Alternatively, you may use do-while loop to do this (force the user to retry).

```
do{
    System.out.print("Enter an integer 1-16: ");
    input = in.nextInt();
    if (input<1 || input>16)
        System.out.println("Error. Must select within 1-16.");

}while(input<1 || input>FibonacciGenerator.upper_limit);
```

Some other suggestion:

1. Make your methods and variables name start with a lower case letter
2. To avoid repeat calculation (for-loop in Fibonacci method), use integer array to store the fibonacci values and pass integer array instead of integer (for small input number such as 16). Another way is to set two more global variables to store the last and second last calculated values.
3. Make upper limit (and/or lower limit) as a global variable for better maintenance

   ```
   public static int upper_limit = 16;
   ```

   and get it in other class as

   ```
   FibonacciGenerator.upper_limit
   ```